# Does continuity implies contunity in the reversed sense?

Tags: continuity, inverse-function

Let $f$ be a bijective real valued continous function with continous inverse defined on a closed interval $C$. Let $a\in C$. Then $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall x \in C $ with $|x-a|<\delta$ we have $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$. Does it follow from this that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall x \in C$ with $|f(x) - f(a)| < \delta$ we have $|x-a|<\epsilon$ ? I believe the answer is yes and this has something to do with the inverse being continous but I couldn't fill in the gaps. I use this proposition to solve a homework question about finding completion of a metric space. I would love to see the proof of this proposition.

Comment: is $f$ assumed to be bijective ,with continuous inverse?

Comment: Yes. In fact the specific function I am working with is $arctan(x)$.

Comment: then what u have written is nothing but the continuity of the inverse and u are right.

Comment: If $f^{-1}$ is continuous isn't that just the definition? $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $w=f(a)$  For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a $\delta >0$ so that for any $u =f(x)$ so that $|w-u| =|f(x)-f(a)|< \implies |f^{-1}(u) -f^{-1}(w)| = |f^{-1}(f(x))-f^{-1}(f(a))| =|x-a| < \epsilon$.  What needs to be proven?

Comment: Your question seems to be:  If $f$ has a continuous inverse, is there any proof that the inverse is continuous?

Comment: Are you asking for a proof that the inverse of a bijective continuous function must be continuous?  Your added condition "with continous inverse" seems bizarre as you are adding as a condition that which you are trying to prove.